# Stuck with getting Scrollview's subview Tag in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I have a scroll view with four subviews inside and paging enabled is true.I want to get the current page or current view's tag of a scrollviews subview.I am getting all the tags once in a while using for loop. Don't know how to split the subviews to identify the Tag.
Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

```
for subview in scrollView.subviews {
    print(subview)
    if ((scrollView.viewWithTag(100)?.tag == View1.tag))
    {
        if (collectionviewarray.count>0)
        {
            CollectionView.reloadData()
            CollectionView.reloadInputViews()
            self.verifyuser()  
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: initially retrieve the scrollview subview after that that check that view contains your view then check the tag is availabe or not

Comment: am getting like this .Optional(<UIView: 0x7f92f5917c20; frame = (0 0; 375 382); autoresize = W+H; tag = 100; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f92f5917d90>>)     .Dont Know how to validate my view with the above array.

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: I have shared my code above.

Answer (score 0):

calculate x contentOffset of the view i.e. 
CGFloat offsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x

run a loop for each view to check if x coordinate of the view is greater than offsetX and less than offsetX + scrollView.width.

Get the tag of that view.